# How to keep the value of a variable the same even after a while loop (Python)

Tags: python, function, pygame

Basically I'm making a function that allows the value of the player's gold to be the same temporally even when they collect a certain "card"

```
def immaculateImmunity(playerGold):
  tempGold = playerGold
  i = 5
  while i>1:
  playerGold
```

So what should I do now as I'm kinda stuck at the moment

Comment: What are you doing with `playerGold`? If it's immutable, what you have is fine; you can't change the value that `tempGold` refers to by doing anything with `playerGold`. Probably related: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: This code is not valid Python (indentation).

Comment: PlayerGold is supposed to refer to how much gold a player is holding. I'm making a "card" where once they get it, their gold can never diminish for 5 turns. Sorry if I sound annoying as am kinda new to all this

Comment: If it should not be changed under some condition then simply do that, only changing the player's gold if the card is not held

Answer (score -1):

Store value in another variable. before using loop after store value again in the previous variable.

```
 def immaculateImmunity(playerGold):
      tempGold = playerGold
      i = 5
      a=i
      while i>1:
        playerGold
      i=a
```